# CentOS Vulnerabilities - Exploits/Payloads

Tags: centos, exploit, security, payload

I'm doing an academic work where I have to **find vulnerabilities in CentOS and show how to take advantage of those same vulnerabilities**.

I'm no hacker and I'm finding this task to be of great difficulty, that is, I see all the security alerts and their descriptions but no explanation of how to take advantage.

Maybe I'm being a little naive but all I want to know is if **there is any tool I can use to show that CentOS 5.0 vulnerability XPTO exists and to show it "working".**

**If possible something like CVE-2007-0001 exploit tool, CVE-2007-0002 payload and so on**.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For locating vulnerabilities, I tend to prefer the more classic approach by default.  [Bugtraq](http://www.google.com/url?url=http://www.securityfocus.com/archive/1&rct=j&ei=3WyrS-TSJ8Sclgei4-zUDg&sa=X&oi=smap&resnum=1&ct=result&cd=2&ved=0CAoQqwMoATAA&q=bugtraq&usg=AFQjCNEp0ejXd08hBIK0g7ATd0ww9KyDZw) and announcement lists for the particular software.  Change logs, et cetera.  Scanners such as [OpenVAS](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&ved=0CAkQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.openvas.org%2F&rct=j&q=openvas&ei=tm6rS7bNHYKdlgfcmdydDg&usg=AFQjCNH24qfJrss11-26DUiUyJzGAYzRrA) can be used for automated verification and testing.

With verifying the scope of impact, it depends on the vulnerability.  When attempting to verify scope of impact, often I seek out the initial release and any vendor specific releases for the vulnerability in question.  At that point, depending upon the nature of the vulnerability, I would be able to verify by manual action or writing my own script.

If full disclosure, sometimes proof of concept code is provided with the initial report.  If not, I would search the Internet and common resources such as [Bugtraq](http://www.google.com/url?url=http://www.securityfocus.com/archive/1&rct=j&ei=3WyrS-TSJ8Sclgei4-zUDg&sa=X&oi=smap&resnum=1&ct=result&cd=2&ved=0CAoQqwMoATAA&q=bugtraq&usg=AFQjCNEp0ejXd08hBIK0g7ATd0ww9KyDZw) and [Packet Storm Security](http://www.packetstormsecurity.org/).

You are going to find it difficult to find professionals to walk you through exploiting a vulnerability due to the dubious nature of the request.  Most vulnerabilities do not require a high level of technical skill to take advantage of.

Comment: http://osvdb.org/ is a good resource as well for more information on vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 2):

script kiddies swear by [metasploit](http://www.metasploit.com/)

Comment: Well metasploit is a tool like any other tool.  Script kiddie tool or not...many professional pen testers use it heavily.  In the right hands the metasploit framework is very powerful I wouldn't call it a script kiddie tool.  But here's the thing with script kiddie stuff.  As a system administrator if you know there's something out there that script kiddies are using and you aren't using it yourself to test your own servers/services/webapps you're asking to be hacked.

Comment: Totally agreeing with you. I'm not dissing the tool, actually it has helped us a lot of times (justifying our consultancy fees). I'm just humoring the OP. Penetration testing is not something you do by a HOW-TO basis, you have to have a large skill-set & spend alot of your resources trying to educate yourself.

Comment: Ah gotcha.  Yes I agree.  Pen testing is definitely an art of it's own that takes quite a bit of knowledge and a lot of thinking outside of the box.  Metasploit is a huge topic by itself.  SANS has a bunch of courses that can get you up to speed on the type of knowledge and tools you need but they are expensive.